# Symmetric matrix of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**

Find the symmetric matrix of a quadratic form $3x_1^2+4x_1x_2+8x_1x_3+4x_2x_3+3x_3^2$

**Attempt**

Let $XAX^t$ = $3x_1^2+4x_1x_2+8x_1x_3+4x_2x_3+3x_3^2$ ,where $A=(a_{ij})$.

Solving we get $a_{11}=3,a_{22}=0,a_{33}=3,a_{12}+a_{21}=4,a_{13}+a_{31}=8,a_{23}+a_{32}=4$

How to proceed after this?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is symmetric , $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$.

Solve using this.